# Mostrar "Loading..." durante navegação entre paginas

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

Quando faço uma chamada `ajax` já consigo mostrar/esconder um gif de loading assim:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
   $('#loadingFull').fadeIn();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
   $('#loadingFull').fadeOut();
});
```

Porem, varias chamadas no sistema são feitas assim, inclusive no menu:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Importar", "Import", "DeliveryService")
```

ou durante um button `submit`.

Como mostrar o GIF durante essa requisição, tem como capturar esse tipo via `javascript`?

Comment: Veja se isso aqui ja não resolve, faz uma função pra chamada ajax: @Html.ActionLink("Importar", "Import", "DeliveryService",null, new { onclick="funcaoDoGif" })

Comment: @AnthraxisBR isso até poderia me atender, porem eu teria que colocar isso em todas as chamadas do sistema, só no menu são mais de 20 chamadas, acaba não sendo boa ideia, queria algo mais genérico.

Comment: Nesse caso nao é viável mesmo, acho que vais ter que simular um 'ajax listener', da uma olhada nessa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596583/javascript-detect-an-ajax-event não com tempo pra poder fazer um resposta decente agora

Comment: Serão para todos os links do seu site, sem exceção?

Comment: @AnthraxisBR fiz um teste rápido aqui com um das respostas e parece que esse é o caminho, obrigado.

Comment: @Randrade sim, quero que o usuário saiba que algo está sendo processado.

Answer (score 1):

O seu `Html.ActionLink()` gerará um `html` similar à este:

```
<a href="/DeliveryService/Import">Importar</a>
```

Feito isso, basta você interceptar as requisições e exibir o GIF.

Abaixo está um exemplo simples de como fazer isso:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#loadingFull').fadeIn(); 
});
```

Note que como a página será atualizada, não necessita do `$('#loadingFull').fadeOut();`.

Veja um exemplo simples abaixo:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('#loadingFull').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
div#loadingFull {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loadingFull"></div>


<a href="#">Importar</a>
```

Para o `submit()` você pode fazer algo similar, mas ao invés do `.click()`, você pode utilizar o [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

> Aparentemente você está utilizando `Asp.NET MVC`. Com isso, você pode adicionar o código em seu arquivo `_Layout.cshtml` que o mesmo servirá para todas as páginas.

[O exemplo do loader eu retirei daqui.](https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL)

Comment: estou usando .net sim, criei um arquivo JS que fica declarado no `layout.cshtml`, ja tinha tentado essa abordagem com o `a`, por algum motivo deu algo errado aqui que não lembro, vou fazer ela com mais atenção aqui e checar. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso, eu uso blockUI da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //blockUI default
        $.blockUI.defaults.message = '<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/ajax_loader.gif")" />';
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.border = 'none';
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.opacity = 0.6;
        $.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        $.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.opacity = 0.6;

    });
```